# How change large dataset between access tiers in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have an ML dataset that consists of 2.7M images, ~1TB. For ML experiments, I uploaded these as blobs in an Azure storage account under "hot" access (which I thought would be appropriate for ML training). While not actively training, I would like this dataset to be in "Archive" mode to avoid accumulating "leaky faucet" charges.

The [document on blob storage access tiers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers#change-the-tier-of-a-blob-in-a-gpv2-or-blob-storage-account) describes how it can be toggled on a per-blob basis, but AFAICT that is per-file (not even per-directory, which would be fine).

Is there a way to toggle the access tier of an entire storage account?

Absent that, what might be a good strategy? Perhaps creating a default-archive-access `data_archive` storage account and do a cloud-based copy to a temporary `data_for_training_purposes` hot-access storage account that I create and delete as needed?